# Как преобразовать поле объекта в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, typescript, объекты

Всем привет!
Есть следующая структура:

```
    const myArr = [
      {  id: 0,
         array: ["example"]
      },
      {  id: 1,
         array: ["example", "test"]
      },
    ]
```

Из массива объектов нужно выбрать те, у которых в array есть поле "test".
Далее нужно поменять "test" на "example2".
В итоге должно получиться:

```
    [
      {  id: 1,
         array: ["example", "example2"]
      },
    ]
```

Написала преобразователь:

```
const replacer = (arr: [] | undefined, text: string, newText: string) =>
        arr?.map(item => item === text ? newText : item);

const answer = myArr
    .map((item) => replacer(item.array, 'test', 'example2'))
    .filter((item) => item.includes('examples2'));
```

Ожидаемо, в answer после .map выводится массив с измененными array, и фильтр уже не
срабатывает.
Не понимаю, как исправить.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу применить фильтр с одновременной подменой "test"

```js
const myArr = [
  { id: 0, array: ["example"] },
  { id: 1, array: ["example", "test"] }
]

const res = myArr.filter(({ array }) => {
  const i = array.indexOf('test')
  return i === -1 ? false : ((array[i] = 'example2'), true)
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все должно хорошо работать, исправьте опечатку, иначе не будет совпадений

```
const answer = myArr
    .map((item) => replacer(item.array, 'test', 'example2'))
    .filter((item) => item.includes('example2'))// ошибка'examples2'
```